# My AndEngine app does not show options menu

Tags: andengine

I'm using AndEngine to develop a simple test application. Everything is good, but the menu options does not show up. I don't know why I don't see the options menu button (the 3-dots touch button on bottom right). Help is much appreciated.

[image]
Here is the piece of code corresponding to the `MenuScene`:

```
    public class MainActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity implements IOnMenuItemClickListener {
        private static int CAMERA_WIDTH ;
        private static int CAMERA_HEIGHT;

        protected static final int MENU_ADD = 0;
        protected static final int MENU_QUIT = MENU_ADD + 1;



        private Font mFont,menuFont;
        private MenuScene mMenuScene;
        Camera camera;
        Scene scene;

        @Override
        public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
//default code
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateResources() throws IOException {
//some code
        }

        @Override
        public Scene onCreateScene() {
 //some code
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClicked(final MenuScene pMenuScene, final IMenuItem pMenuItem, final float pMenuItemLocalX, final float pMenuItemLocalY) {
            switch(pMenuItem.getID()) {
            case MENU_ADD:
                /* Restart the animation. */
                Log.i("hello", "Menu ADD CLICKED");
                return true;

            case MENU_QUIT:
                /* End Activity. */
                this.finish();
                return true;

            default:
                return false;
            }
        }

        protected MenuScene createMenuScene() {
            final MenuScene menuScene = new MenuScene(this.camera, new AlphaMenuSceneAnimator());

            final IMenuItem resetMenuItem = new ColorMenuItemDecorator(new TextMenuItem(MENU_ADD, this.menuFont, "ADD ITEM", this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()), new Color(1,0,0), new Color(0,0,0));
            menuScene.addMenuItem(resetMenuItem);
            final IMenuItem quitMenuItem = new ColorMenuItemDecorator(new TextMenuItem(MENU_QUIT, this.menuFont, "QUIT", this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()), new Color(1,0,0), new Color(0,0,0));

            menuScene.addMenuItem(quitMenuItem);
            menuScene.buildAnimations();
            menuScene.setBackgroundEnabled(false);
            menuScene.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
            return menuScene;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(final int pKeyCode, final KeyEvent pEvent) {
            if(pKeyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU && pEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if(this.scene.hasChildScene()) {
                    /* Remove the menu and reset it. */
                    this.mMenuScene.back();
                } else {
                    /* Attach the menu. */
                    this.scene.setChildScene(this.mMenuScene, false, true, true);
                }
                return true;
            } else {
                return super.onKeyDown(pKeyCode, pEvent);
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Please edit the question and reduce the code to the minimum amount needed to demonstrate the problem.  Also, change the title to something that we can understand what the question is so we can figure out if we might know the answer.  We are trying to answer many questions, and when we see this much code, we often skip it because it takes too long to work out what part of it is important.  See the help center about writing good questions for more information.

Comment: @GuySchalnat just did it!